# Python - Running a command then inputting when prompted automatically

Tags: python, ssh-keys

As part of a larger script, I'm running `ssh-keygen` to generate an RSA public key. I'm not planning on using a passphrase or changing the default folder location. However, I still have to deal with the prompts from `ssh-keygen` for the file name and passphrase. How can I circumvent having to deal with those prompts, either using the options for `ssh-keygen` or in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass them as parameters to avoid need for any input:

```
ssh-keygen -q -N '' -C 'generated key' -t rsa -f /path/to/key
```

Answer (score 1):

In general such problems can be solved with pexpect: http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/#doc which is Python wrapper of expect. It lets you wait for a certain string to be printed and then react by sending a response, like it was typed in the terminal.

Comment: This is a neat little module, I'll check it out.